# merge common keys and its value individually in python dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

i have seen lot of answers related to my question but none of them solved my question

here is the input question:

```
data = { "data": [{ key1:word},{ key1:hello},{key2:hey},{key2:hi}]}
```

expected output:

```
[{key1:word, key2:hey}, {key1:hello, key2:hi}]
```

if i add key3 then this is the wanted output:

```
data = { "data": [{ key1:word},{ key1:hello},{key2:hey},{key2:hi}, 
         {key3:somedata},{key3:somedata2}]}

# WANTED OUTPUT BELOW
 
[ {key1:word, key2:hey, key3:somedata}, {key1:hello, key2:hi, 
 key3:somedata2} ]
```

here is what i have tried:

```
 for key,items in data.items():
    if key == "key1":
        do something
    if key == "key2":
        do something
```

but the above cannot be used for 1000 key pair values, so the code should be dynamic.
in future key4, key5, key6....etc can be added so each key items i cant define in condition.

Comment: data = { key1:value1},{ key1:hello},{key2:value2},{key2:value3}   isn't proper python... please share your actual code.

Comment: @Cargo23, Yes it is, it will be converted to a Tuple!

Comment: im sorry i have now updated the question

Comment: Could you explain why they are matched like `{key1:value1, key2:value2}, {key1:hello, key2:value3}` and not like `{key1:value1, key2:value3}, {key1:hello, key2:value2}`  for example

Comment: @RobinDillen Hi, its not matched its just a value not matched !  i will change if its confusing.

Comment: @Titanium Please clarify your question and add reproducible data, not just "key1:value1" so others will understand your intentions and will be able to attach working code.

Comment: I have slightly changed the input and expected output. please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a neat solution as long as the count of all keys is the same!

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [{"key1": "value1"}, {"key1": "hello"}, {"key2": "value2"}, {"key2": "value3"}, {"key3": "test1"},
        {"key3": "test2"}]

data.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.keys())[0]) # you need to sort for groupby to work in every case
grouped = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: list(x.keys())[0])]
# = [[{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key1': 'hello'}], [{'key2': 'value2'}, {'key2': 'value3'}], [{'key3': 'test1'}, {'key3': 'test2'}]]
output = [{k:v for dic in t for k,v in dic.items()} for t in zip(*grouped)]
# source https://stackoverflow.com/a/43529214/10875953
print(output) 
# prints [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'test1'}, {'key1': 'hello', 'key2': 'value3', 'key3': 'test2'}]
```

Comment: Hi robin, thanks for the response. can you try the expected ouput like this below

[{key1:word, key2:hey, key3:somedata}, {key1:hello, key2:hi, 
 key3:somedata2}]

Comment: @Titanium i edited my answer

Comment: Oh just now saw you edited response, i think this is it. it works !!

Comment: can you please check out my new thread ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72487303/want-to-add-left-out-string-in-matched-string

Answer (score 0):

Interesting request..... I think this might be what you needed?

```py
data = [{ "key1":"value1"},{ "key1":"hello"},{"key2":"value2"},{"key2":"value3"}] 

odd_entries = data[::2]  # Iterate by twos, starting at 0
even_entries = data[1::2]  # Iterate by twos, starting at 1

print(list(zip(odd_entries, even_entries)))
```

> [({'key1': 'value1'}, {'key1': 'hello'}), ({'key2': 'value2'}, {'key2': 'value3'})]

Comment: Hi, the key1 and key2 should be paired in single curly brackets. and also the code should be dynamic what if you add {key3:"some data"} so the output should be {key1:word, key2:hey, key3:"some data"}, {key1:hello, key2:hi, key3:"some data"}

Comment: I have changed the example question more specifically if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you to understand the problem

```
data = { "data": [{"key1":"word"},{ "key1":"hello"},{"key2":"hey"},{"key2":"hi"}, 
     {"key3":"somedata"},{"key3":"somedata2"}]}  

dic1 = {}
dic2 = {}

[dic2.update(dic) if tuple(dic)[0] in dic1.keys() else dic1.update(dic) for dic in data["data"]]
```

Above list comprehension can be re-written as blow(For better understanding)

```
    for dic in data["data"]:
       if tuple(dic)[0] in dic1.keys():
           dic2.update(dic)
       else:
           dic1.update(dic)
```

OutPut:

dic1

```
{'key1': 'word', 'key2': 'hey', 'key3': 'somedata'}
```

dic2

```
{'key1': 'hello', 'key2': 'hi', 'key3': 'somedata2'}
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(data["data"])):` is correct, though it is unpythonic. Just loop over `data["data"]`.

Comment: Also if you have 3 times "key1" your code will not work because you only have 2 dicts

Comment: Yes as Robin pointed out, extra key1,key2,key3 for the third time will cause problem.